# How to center two TextViews beside ImageView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to achieve following output:

[image]

But what I get is:

[image]

I can't seem to figure out how to center the two `TextViews`. The code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/chat_room_image_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- Progress bar -->
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/chat_room_image_progressbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxHeight="40dp"
            android:minHeight="40dp"
            android:minWidth="40dp"
            android:maxWidth="40dp"
            android:theme="@style/progressColor"
            android:layout_margin="15dp" />

        <!-- user's avatar image -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/chat_room_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chat_room_title_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/chat_room_image_layout"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/chat_room_image_layout">

        <!-- user names -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chat_room_users_text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/blackColor"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <!-- last message -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chat_room_last_message_text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="@color/blackColor"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The avatar is being set dynamically with the height and weight of `50dp`. I tired to follow [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62353940/how-to-set-images-on-same-row-as-two-textviews) but without any succsus. How can I center those two textviews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="56dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <!-- user's avatar image -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingStart="15dp"
        android:paddingEnd="15dp"/>


    <!-- Progress bar -->
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/chat_room_image_progressbar"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ..>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chat_room_title_layout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- user names -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chat_room_users_text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            .../>

        <!-- last message -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chat_room_last_message_text"
            android:text="text2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            ... />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I added

> android:layout_centerVertical="true"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/chat_room_image_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- Progress bar -->
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/chat_room_image_progressbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxHeight="40dp"
            android:minHeight="40dp"
            android:minWidth="40dp"
            android:maxWidth="40dp"
            android:theme="@style/progressColor"
            android:layout_margin="15dp" />

        <!-- user's avatar image -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/chat_room_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chat_room_title_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        ***android:layout_centerVertical="true"***
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/chat_room_image_layout"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/chat_room_image_layout">

        <!-- user names -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chat_room_users_text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/blackColor"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <!-- last message -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chat_room_last_message_text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="@color/blackColor"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your layout file, there are two `RelativeLayout`s as well as one `LinearLayout`. Having many `ViewGroup`s may be bad for performance, especially if you want to use the layout for a row of some really long list. So I'd like to suggest another option: with a `ConstraintLayout` you get rid of the nested `ViewGroup`s

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <!-- user's avatar image -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/chat_room_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"/>

    <!-- Progress bar -->
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/chat_room_image_progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxHeight="40dp"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:minWidth="40dp"
        android:maxWidth="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp" />

    <!-- invisible helper: 15dp + 50dp + 15dp = 80dp -->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="80dp"/>

    <!-- user names -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chat_room_users_text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/chat_room_last_message_text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/blackColor"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <!-- last message -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chat_room_last_message_text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chat_room_users_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:textColor="@color/blackColor"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

For more information on `ConstraintLayout`: [Build a Responsive UI with ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)